# Can I use MongoDB for Java Content Repository?

Tags: java, mongodb, jcr

Can I use MongoDB for JCR storing file (XML file)?

Answer (score 3):

The next version of Apache JackRabbit, codename *Oak* includes a Mongo-based store - a MicroKernel in Oak terms. You can see some details at [OAK-619: Lock-free MongoMK implementation](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OAK-619).

Answer (score 2):

No - MongoDB does not use traditional locking which as far as I know is required for JCR. JCR also includes Full-Text Search as packaged with Lucene, whereas you can do full text search in Mongo (using multikeys) you may not have some other features of full-text search engines (stemming, ranking, etc).

At the end of the day, JCR is really meant for use with a RDBMS and also a full-text index.

Comment: Actually MongoDB provides stemming, ranking, stop-words removal etc. For more info see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/. Of' course Lucene (and all its derivatives like Solr) are much more powerful (e.g. you can create your own stemmers, etc).

Comment: Brian, with all due respect every sentence of your answer is wrong. JCR can work with filesystem, or with mongo, or on top of an RDBMS as it's back end. The following is my code which is the JCR initializer which works for both MongoDB AND RDBMS:

https://github.com/Clay-Ferguson/meta64/blob/master/src/main/java/com/meta64/mobile/repo/OakRepository.java

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Apache Jackrabbit Oak fully supports MongoDB, and mongo is actually the best performing backend you can use. Here is an example of how meta64 repository initialization is done:

https://github.com/Clay-Ferguson/meta64/blob/master/src/main/java/com/meta64/mobile/repo/OakRepository.java